# Binary Classification Model Inaccurate

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm doing Binary Classification in the form of a XOR gate using ML.NET and SdcaLogisticRegression.

The problem I have is that the model outputs inaccurate predictions for the inputs I give it. For example it predicts a value of 0 with probability 0.459 for inputs 0.8 and 0.2.

Could you please look if my code or algorithm are not suitable for making a XOR Gate?

I trained the model with various amounts of training data and received similar results every time (between 200 and 1M rows in the training data file).

```
IDataView trainingData = context.Data.LoadFromTextFile<XorInput>(trainDataFile, separatorChar: ',', hasHeader: true);

IDataView testData = context.Data.LoadFromTextFile<XorInput>(testDataFile, separatorChar: ',', hasHeader: true);

var trainingPipeline = context.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "Inputs").Append(context.BinaryClassification.Trainers.SdcaLogisticRegression(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features"));

ITransformer trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingData);

XorInput sampleInput = new XorInput { Inputs = new float[] {0.8f, 0.2f } };

var predEngine = context.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<XorInput, XorOutputPrediction>(trainedModel);

var resultprediction = predEngine.Predict(sampleInput);

Console.WriteLine($"=============== Single Prediction  ===============");
Console.WriteLine($"Inputs: {sampleInput.Inputs[0]}, {sampleInput.Inputs[1]}  | Prediction: {(Convert.ToInt16(resultprediction.Prediction))} | Probability: {resultprediction.Probability} ");
Console.WriteLine($"==================================================");
```

Just for reference, my classes XorInput and XorOutputPrediction look like this:

```
public class XorInput
    {
        [LoadColumn(0), ColumnName("Label")]
        public bool Label;

        [LoadColumn(1,2)]
        [VectorType(2)]
        //[ColumnName("Features")]
        public float[] Inputs;
    }

    public class XorOutputPrediction
    {
        [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
        public bool Prediction { get; set; }

        public float Probability { get; set; }

        public float Score { get; set; }
    }
```

The data contained in trainDataFile and testDataFile looks like this:

```
0,  0.9173474,  0.8329648
0,  0.4942033,  0.1281894
0,  0.4558121,  0.1869916
1,  0.738331,   0.4427712
0,  0.8739759,  0.5859472
1,  0.7447554,  0.1089314
1,  0.2433814,  0.6192696
```

For input values of 0.8 and 0.2 I expect an output prediction of 1.

Comment: Did you try reversing the inputs 0.8 and 0.2?

Comment: I've just retrained the model with ~32k rows and tried again achieving a correct prediction for both 0.8 and 0.2 but the probability is only about 0.52. How would I go about increasing this? Edit: After retraining it again incorrectly predicts a 0 for both reversed and non-reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the training algorithm to Fast Forest and got the accuracy up to 99.97% with correct outputs.